# Python in Rhino 7, exporting coordinates from Rhino with Python into excel

Tags: python, excel

I have some difficulty with data collected in Python for Rhino 7.
I do select set points on one object and get the coordinates for each object in the global world coordinates.
Now I need to get these transferred within this python program from Rhino into an excel sheet, showing me the object and the related point coordinates, i.e. I have one circle "A", where I have set 6 points to. I need to have the excel sheet showing like following:
Circle "A" : "point_1,x,y,z", "point_2,x,y,z" and so on....

Does anyone have some suggestions on how to get the results transferred in this way into an excel sheet?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Kai